# Running two spring boot instances

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, microservices

I am using Intellij Idea IDE version 2019.2.3 and I want to run two instances of my spring boot application in different ports, but I got just one running instance.
I start the application in the port 8081 and after it runs, I change the port to 8083 and run it again in parallel with the previous one but i got this error :

> `The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8083 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

And when I come to the browser i found that the first port stopped working, when the application runs successfully in the last port`

I have tried to add a new "run configuration" but got the same problem.

[image]

Comment: Where do you set the port?

Comment: In bootstrap.properties file

Comment: Try using 2 different run configurations with the port set in the [VM Options field](https://i.imgur.com/QCgGrsD.png)  like this: `-Dserver.port=9090`. Use different port for each configuration so that you can run 2 instances.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the **VM options** field of the Sprint Boot run/debug configuration to define the port via the

`-Dserver.port=9090`

property. If the ports are different, you'll be able to start multiple instances:

[image: Running 2 instances on different ports]

The screenshot shows 2 run configurations started at the same time, one has `-Dserver.port=9090` VM option, another has `-Dserver.port=9091`.

Comment: Along with this I also had to mark the "Allow multiple instances" option in Run configuration as mentioned in the next answer.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to use 'Allow parallel run' run/debug configuration option in combination with server.port: ${random.int(value,[max])} spring boot's property.
For instance, server.port: ${random.int(8088,8099)} so that while running the config the idea will pick some random port from the provided range as result you don't need to spawn multiple run/debug configurations if it's not necessary.
In order not to get in collision please use a wider range.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps for the latest Intellij version where VM options might not be shown by default in Run Configuration

1. Edit *Run/Debug Configuration*

[image: Edit Configuration]

2. On the right side click "*Modify Option*" and choose from the drop-down "*Add VM options*"
   [image: Add VM options]
3. Set the following command and the desired port in the newly appeared filed
   [image: Add server port]
4. Save and run the project

Answer (score 0):

you can create instance or copy of an application by clicking "**Run** Button -> **Run Configuration**".

Then right click on your "**Application name**" -> click on "**Duplicate**".

Then choose "**Arguments**" tab -> In "**VM Arguments**" type this.

> -Dserver.port=8001

8001 is the port number you can mention your port over there.
screenshot below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This video gives one option that works.  Make several instances with different port numbers.  Alternatively, you can set server.port=0 and each instance will have a random port that will be different.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRb1io4Ewuc

Answer (score -1):

another straight way is to use:

```
server.port=0.   (in application.properties file) or
-Dserver.port=0 (in VM arguments)
```

This way random port number will automatically be assigned to the newly created instance

Comment: True.  You will get random port numbers but, you will still not be allowed to run in parallel and you won't be able to open a 2nd instance.